# Replacing four letter words in a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that reads input from one file, replaces all four letter words with 'xxxx', and writes that to another file. I know that this problem is already up on the site and I've googled to find other problems, but they're all the same. I also played around with the code, but still couldn't reach a solution.

```
def censor(filename):
    'string ==> None, creates file censored.txt in current folder with all 4 letter words replaces with string xxxx'
    import string
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    infile2 = open('censored.txt','w')
    for word in infile:
        words = word.split()
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            words.strip(string.punctuation)
            if len(word) == 4:
                words[i] == 'xxxx'
                infile2.write(words[i])
```

I know this is just a mess of code that doesn't work, but I figured it's worth posting anything. I had an idea of stripping the punctuation from the text so that it doesn't count some 4 letter words as 5 with punctuation, splitting the words into a list to change the four letter words, then joining them back together in the original order, only with the words replaced. So "I like to work." would end up "I xxxx to xxxx."

I also looked at another similar post on this site and found a solution that does work, but doesn't address the punctuation problem.

```
def maybe_replace(word, length=4):
    if len(word) == length:
        return 'xxxx'
    else:
        return word

def replacement(filename):
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    outfile = open('censored.txt','w')
    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        newWords = [maybe_replace(word) for word in words]
        newLine = ' '.join(newWords)
        outfile.write(newLine + '\n')
    outfile.close()
    infile.close()
```

So in this case, if I have a list of words like "Frog, boot, cat, dog." it would return "Frog, boot, xxxx xxxx"

I also found another solution using regex, but I'm still a novice and really can't understand that solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the code you are not able to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex solution is pretty simple:

```
import re

text = """
    I also found another solution using 
    regex, but I'm still a novice and 
    really can't understand that solution. 
    Any help would be appreciated.
"""

print re.sub(r'\b\w{4}\b', 'xxxx', text)
```

The regex matches:

- `\b`, which is a word boundary. It matches the beginning or end of a word.
- `\w{4}` matches four word characters (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_`).
- `\b` is yet another word boundary.

The output is:

```
I xxxx found another solution using 
regex, but I'm still a novice and 
really can't understand xxxx solution. 
Any xxxx would be appreciated.
```

Comment: Okay, the explanation made it a bit simpler. Thank you for the help. Also, should I look into learning regex more? I read somewhere that it's really powerful and beneficial, but I don't want to complicate things for myself, since I'm still learning.

Comment: @iKyriaki: I'd start by learning Python first. Regex is useful, but you should do stuff without it before you can actually appreciate how useful it is.

Answer (score 1):

The second piece of your code has problem with `words = line.split()`.
By default, it splits on space, so ',' was counted as a part of your word.

If you really don't want to touch regex, here is my suggestion (still a little regex involved):

```
import re
words = re.split('[\W]+', line)
```

this asks python to split the line on non-alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 0):

There we have my answer! :)

```
import string as s
alfanum = s.ascii_letters + s.digits

def maybe_replace(arg, length=4):
    word = ""
    for t in arg: word += t if t in alfanum else ""

    if len(word) == length: 
        if len(arg)>4: return 'xxxx'+arg[4:]
        else: return 'xxxx'
    else: 
      return arg

text = "Frog! boot, cat, dog. bye, bye!"
words = text.split()
print words
print [maybe_replace(word) for word in words]

>>> ['Frog!', 'boot,', 'cat,', 'dog.', 'bye,', 'bye!']
>>> ['xxxx!', 'xxxx,', 'cat,', 'dog.', 'bye,', 'bye!']
```